# Alias scope is causing uncertain behaviour

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm learning SQL and working on trying to understand a query difference.

Running the query below where the alias `pn` is defined in the outer `FROM` section and the inner sql references it.

Query

```
SELECT 
  (select pn.province_name from province_names as pn where pn.province_id=p.province_id) AS Province
FROM 
  patients p,
  province_names pn
group by
  p.province_id
having 
  COUNT(case when p.gender = 'M' then 1 end) > count(case when p.gender = 'F' then 1 end)
```

The results I get are strange with `NULLS`

```
Province
Alberta
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

Defining the **outer** alias `pn` also inside the subquery suddenly the query works as expected as below:

Query

```
SELECT 
  (select pn.province_name from province_names as pn where pn.province_id=p.province_id) AS Province
FROM 
  patients p,
  province_names pn
group by
  p.province_id
having 
  COUNT(case when p.gender = 'M' then 1 end) > count(case when p.gender = 'F' then 1 end)
```

Result

```
Province
Alberta
British Columbia
Manitoba
Newfoundland and Labrador
Nova Scotia
Ontario
Saskatchewan
```

I'm uncertain why the **outer** scope variant isn't picked up **inside the subquery** on the first sql. Is there a rule that defines scope, my searching on google hasn't shown anything I can take advantage of to understand this behaviour. Is the **outer** scope not visible in the **inner sub-query** scope?

Comment: a comma between two tables means you make a cross join , since more than 30  years JOIN are used to avoid problems and addionally your first query is the same as the second, third you must name all tables unique so that MySQL can identiofy the table you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're observing stems from the way SQL resolves table and column names in subqueries.

Your query has a subquery in the `SELECT` clause. This kind of subquery is called a correlated subquery because it references a column (`province_id`) from the outer query.

It is trying to fetch the `province_name` based on the `province_id` from the `patients` table. In the first version of the query, the subquery references `pn.province_name` and `pn.province_id` but does not define the alias `pn` within the subquery itself. This is where the issue lies.

Logically, when the SQL engine encounters a column reference inside a subquery, it first tries to resolve it within the subquery's scope. If it cannot find it in the current scope, it then looks in the outer query's scope. In your first query, the subquery sees the reference to `pn.province_name` and `pn.province_id`, but there is no definition of `pn` in the subquery. Thus, it attempts to look at the outer scope, where it does find the definition. But here's the catch: when you join `patients` and `province_names` without a join condition in the outer query, you're essentially performing a Cartesian product, and every row in `patients` is combined with every row in `province_names`. This mismatch causes the `NULL` values you're seeing.

In the second query you provided (which is actually identical to the first, but I assume you intended to define `pn` inside the subquery), by defining the alias `pn` within the subquery, it immediately resolves the columns to the right table and doesn't consider the outer scope's Cartesian product. This gives you the expected result.

To follow the best practice you need to explicitly specify the join condition using the `JOIN` keyword instead of using commas in the `FROM` clause. This makes the query more readable and avoids unintentional Cartesian products:

```
SELECT 
  (select pn_inner.province_name from province_names as pn_inner where pn_inner.province_id=p.province_id) AS Province
FROM 
  patients p
LEFT JOIN
  province_names pn ON p.province_id = pn.province_id
GROUP BY
  p.province_id
HAVING 
  COUNT(case when p.gender = 'M' then 1 end) > COUNT(case when p.gender = 'F' then 1 end)
```

Comment: Brilliant explanation. Thank you Amira!!!